# Creating a random dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, random

I would like to create a random dictionary starting from the following array:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

In particular, I would like to have as keys of the dictionary all the elements of the array and as corresponding keys, *randomly pick some values from that array except the value that corresponds to the key*

An example of expected output should be something like:

```
Randomdict = {1: [2, 4], 2: [1,3,5] 3: [2] 4: [2,3,5] 5: [1,2,3,4]}
```

And last but not least all keys should have at least 1 value

Comment: Hi could you provide an expected output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with the `random` module and comprehensions:

```
from random import sample, randrange

d = {i: sample([j for j in lst if i != j], randrange(1, len(lst) - 1))
     for i in lst}
```

If you first use `random.seed(0)` for reproducible data, you will get:

```
{1: [3, 2], 2: [4, 3], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 1]}
{1: [3], 2: [1], 3: [4, 1], 4: [1, 3]}
{1: [3, 2], 2: [3, 4], 3: [4], 4: [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Might needs some tweaks

```
from random import randrange, sample

q = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = {}
for i in q:
    n = randrange(len(q)-1)
    a[i] = sample(q, n)

print(a)
```